# MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException in DBMigrator when using MongoDB API of Cosmos DB

Tags: abp, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

My goal is to run abp framework on a serverless instance of azure cosmos using the MongoDB API.

I've followed the instructions in document [How to use Cosmos DB in ABP?](https://community.abp.io/posts/using-cosmosdb-with-the-abp-framework-via-mongodb-api-x47bjeik)

I've created a serverless azure cosmos instance and replaced the mongo connection string in the two  appsettings.json files with the one from the azure cosmos instance.

Running DBMigrator, I am getting the exception below.

- Did something change since the documentation was created?
- How should this be fixed?

**The index path corresponding to the specified order-by item is excluded.**

MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Command aggregate failed: Error=2, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 2304f974-560f-4fa2-98f7-5dd5c507f778; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 2304f974-560f-4fa2-98f7-5dd5c507f778; Reason: (Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: 2304f974-560f-4fa2-98f7-5dd5c507f778; Reason: (Message: {"Errors":["The index path corresponding to the specified order-by item is excluded."]}
ActivityId: 2304f974-560f-4fa2-98f7-5dd5c507f778, Request URI: /apps/d59013fc-b555-446c-bb1d-bda7cf3fc334/services/b9f3401c-9689-4942-ace8-69706d4dab8a/partitions/119e7a08-8efa-4463-8dd8-a0cd2eb66e1e/replicas/133267263010309566p/, RequestStats: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Tracing.TraceData.ClientSideRequestStatisticsTraceDatum, SDK: Windows/10.0.17763 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.18.0);););.
Source=MongoDB.Driver.Core
StackTrace:
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ProcessResponse(ConnectionId connectionId, CommandMessage responseMessage) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.d__20.MoveNext()
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.d__20`1.MoveNext() at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadOperationExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.ReadCommandOperation`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext() at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AggregateOperation`1.d__65.MoveNext()
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.AggregateOperation`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__64.MoveNext() at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.<ExecuteReadOperationAsync>d__3`1.MoveNext()
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<ExecuteReadOperationAsync>d__99`1.MoveNext()
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<AggregateAsync>d__23`1.MoveNext()
at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<UsingImplicitSessionAsync>d__107`1.MoveNext()
at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.d__16`1.MoveNext() at Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.MongoDB.MongoTenantRepository.<GetListAsync>d__4.MoveNext() at Castle.DynamicProxy.AsyncInterceptorBase.<ProceedAsynchronous>d__14`1.MoveNext()
at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAbpMethodInvocationAdapterWithReturnValue`1.<ProceedAsync>d__7.MoveNext() at Volo.Abp.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.<InterceptAsync>d__2.MoveNext() at Volo.Abp.Castle.DynamicProxy.CastleAsyncAbpInterceptorAdapter`1.d__3`1.MoveNext()
at RoboMentorsV2.Data.RoboMentorsV2DbMigrationService.d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Users\juchy\source\repos\RoboMentorsV2\aspnet-core\src\RoboMentorsV2.Domain\Data\RoboMentorsV2DbMigrationService.cs:line 51
at RoboMentorsV2.DbMigrator.DbMigratorHostedService.d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\juchy\source\repos\RoboMentorsV2\aspnet-core\src\RoboMentorsV2.DbMigrator\DbMigratorHostedService.cs:line 36
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.d__12.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()
at RoboMentorsV2.DbMigrator.Program.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\juchy\source\repos\RoboMentorsV2\aspnet-core\src\RoboMentorsV2.DbMigrator\Program.cs:line 30

**What I Tried**
I've followed the instructions in document [How to use Cosmos DB in ABP?](https://community.abp.io/posts/using-cosmosdb-with-the-abp-framework-via-mongodb-api-x47bjeik)

I've created a serverless azure cosmos instance and replaced the mongo connection string in the two  appsettings.json files with the one from the azure cosmos instance.

**What I am expecting**
My goal is to run abp framework on a serverless instance of azure cosmos using the MongoDB API.